# Reading String From Stdin

Tags: c++, string, stdin

I have this code that reads from `stdin` into a `char*`.   Is it possible to do this directly into a `std::string`?

```
int size = std::atoi(m_content_size);
char* buffer;
buffer = (char*)malloc(size);
fread(buffer, 1, size, stdin);

...

free(buffer);
```

I suppose I could do `std::string sBuffer(buffer)`, but I'm hoping there is a better alternative.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this C or C++ that you want to use?

Comment: @EdHeal: Since there is no `std::string` in C, it must be C++ (albeit with a strong C accent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably read into a vector of chars or so, just so as to not give the impression that you have "text" if you really have arbitrary binary data:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// ...

std::vector<char> buf(size);
std::cin.read(buf.data(), buf.size());

// all done, will clean up after itself!
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance -- are `std::cin` and `stdin` equivalent?

Comment: @Eric: `std::cin` is the istream that wraps the same data stream that the `stdin` file-pointer does. They're not the same thing, but they access the same data. Iostreams are the standard C++ I/O idiom, so I prefer to give a C++ answer. `std::fread(buf.data(), 1, buf.size(), stdin)` would be the corresponding `FILE*` code (using `<cstdio>`).

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  I had, for some reason, always thought cin stood for console-input.  I will test out your solution in a bit.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

```
int size = std::atoi(m_content_size);
std::string buffer(size);
fread(&buffer[0], 1, size, stdin);
```

although you could use `cin` (and a better suited container, if it's not a string but just raw binary data)

Comment: Thanks. Does this require any memory deallocation?

Comment: Nope, it's handled automatically by `std::string` as usual.

Comment: Thank you.  I almost went with this, but I'm trying to reduce my usage of C libraries (stdio.h).  +1 for the valid answer, anyway.

Comment: Then follow @Kerrek SB's suggestion; I left the C IO function because I assumed you had a good reason to use it over `cin` in your program.